# For a given value of k, find the size of smallest subarray that contains all the elements which are <=k in linear time

Tags: arrays

Given array A is unsorted.

I want to know both approches, using sorting and without sorting.

How it can be done using sorting in linear time?

First I searched for all elemnts which are smaller than k, then I tried to find the relative distances among the elements that i found in first scan by taking a variable count such that I initialised the count with the index of first element I got.

Then adding the relative distance of next element found. This is what I thought.

I prefer java, however I am interested in approch.

Comment: Language?, and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Look at the quicksort algorithm.  Its first pass should give you the size you're after in linear time.

Comment: @ QuakeCore...first i searched for all elemnts which are smaller than k.. then i tried to find the relative distances among the elements that i found in first scan by Taking a variable count such that i intialised the count with the index of first element i got.. then adding the relative distance of next element found, and so on.. this is what i thought.
I prefer java.. however i am interested in approch.

Comment: @thebjorn 8.. can you please elaborate?

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question.  You should update your question instead of putting details in the comments.

Comment: @thebjorn.. i edited the question.

Comment: @UjjwalSaini You do not require sorting brother.

Comment: You should post example input and expected output (with explanations) to avoid people misunderstanding your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I've interpreted the requirements correctly, ie.:

```py
print smallest([6, 1, 5, 3, 2, 7], 4)   # [1, 5, 3, 2]
print smallest([6], 4)                  # []
print smallest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)      # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print smallest([6, 1, 2, 3, 4], 4)      # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

then you can do this in sub-linear time by finding the first non-conforming element from each side:

```py
def smallest(a, k):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return []

    i = 0
    j = len(a) - 1
    while i < len(a) and a[i] > k:
        i += 1

    while j >= 0 and a[j] > k:
        j -= 1

    return a[i:j+1]   # subarray starting at i and ending before j+1
```